# aws code build, code deploy, CI/CD pipeline error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1
environment_variables:
    plaintext:
        S3_BUCKET: "test"
phases:
    install:
        commands:
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Build started on `date`
            - ng build --prod -c=staging --output-hashing all
    post_build:
         commands:
            - aws s3 rm s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - aws s3 cp dist s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
    files:
        - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'dist*'
    discard-paths: yes
```

error:
cloudwatch logs

pyenv: version `2.7.15' is not installed (set by /codebuild/output/src298161583/src/.python-version)

2020-07-06T19:33:12.830-04:00

2020-07-06T19:33:12.830-04:00
[Container] 2020/07/06 23:33:12 Command did not exit successfully aws s3 rm s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive exit status 1

Comment: Which [CB runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) is that?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 aws/codebuild/standard:4.0

Comment: The command `aws s3 rm s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive` looks correct. If you `echo ${S3_BUCKET}` what does it give?

Comment: Btw, I assume `test` is not the real bucket name which you are trying to use?

Comment: it is writing bucketname "test"  i mean real bucketname

Comment: these are logs

[Container] 2020/07/07 03:43:38 Running command echo ${S3_BUCKET}

2020-07-06T23:43:39.109-04:00
stagedeploytest

Comment: Is this `test` or `stagedeploytest`? Also is `stagedeploytest` actually yours?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217345/discussion-between-iosdev-and-marcin).

Comment: Any luck with the issue?

Comment: no luck @Marvin :(

Comment: issue solved :) this is issue related to .python-version.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. You can add an answer to your own question for future reference if you want. I'm curious what do you mean by `.python-version` and why it was an issue?

Comment: that is some python related file , we are currently not using it, 'cause of pyenv: version `2.7.15' is not installed (set by /codebuild/output/src298161583/src/.python-version) error,  post_build fails, i removed that file

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try and upgrade to [buildspec version 0.2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-versions)? e.g.

```yaml
version: 0.2
env:
    variables:
        S3_BUCKET: "test"
phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            python: 3.8
        commands:
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Build started on `date`
            - ng build --prod -c=staging --output-hashing all
    post_build:
         commands:
            - aws s3 rm s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - aws s3 cp dist s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
    files:
        - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'dist*'
    discard-paths: yes
```

Based on the output

> pyenv: version `2.7.15' is not installed (set by /codebuild/output/src298161583/src/.python-version)

It seems like something is requesting a Python runtime. In one of the comments, you mention that the CodeBuild Docker image `Ubuntu 18.04 aws/code-build/standard:4.0` is used. Regrettably, this image only support [Python version 3.7 and 3.8](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/ubuntu/standard/4.0/runtimes.yml#L71-L80) (and not version 2.x), hence the addition of the `python: 3.8` in [runtime-versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.phases.install.runtime-versions) in the updated buildspec above. Consequently, it is not unlikely that there will still be errors that you have to solve.